# How to create a button to go back to the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, scroll

I created a button with a link to go back to the top of the page.

Here is the JS code :

```
(function ($) {

/*--Scroll Back to Top Button Show--*/

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#back-to-top').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#back-to-top').fadeOut();
    }
});

//Click event scroll to top button jquery

$('#back-to-top').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},600);
    return false;
});

})(jQuery);
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a id="back-to-top" href="#">
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up fa-4x"></i>
</a>
```

It works very well, but I want to create a button instead of a link.

I tested the following HTML code but it does not work. There is the button but it does not go back up the page :

```
<button type="button" id="back-to-top" href="#">
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up fa-4x"></i>
</button>
```

How to create a button to go back to the top of the page ?

Comment: The code to do this with a `button` is identical to that with an `a`, as such your code already works: https://jsfiddle.net/k8qyLbgt/. If it's not working for you firstly check the console for errors, and then update the question with the code the reproduces the problem

Comment: does the link with the same id happen to be on the same page, above the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is same code for both. But notice if you didn't remove  tag, than could happend that you have duplicate id and button will not work

```js
(function ($) {

/*--Scroll Back to Top Button Show--*/

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#back-to-top').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#back-to-top').fadeOut();
    }
});

//Click event scroll to top button jquery

$('#back-to-top').click(function(){

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},600);
    return false;
});

})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 1000px;
}
button{
  position: fixed;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
a{
  position: fixed;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="back-to-top" type="button">
  Button
</button>
```

Comment: Kovchuck Thank you, but you just need one button. For the purposes of my theme, I want to replace "a" with "button". If I do that, back up does not work anymore.

Comment: I updated answer to just one button, as you see it is still working, so please compare with your code, maybe you have just some typo error

Answer (score 1):

The javascript to take you to the top of a page is...

```
window.scrollTo(0,0)
```

So when incorporated as a link, it will look like this...

```
<a href="javascript:window.scrollTo(0,0);">Go to top</a>
```

Or as a button, it will look like this...

```
<button onclick="window.scrollTo(0,0);">Go to top</button>
```